# OpenCV Error: Null pointer (create() called for the missing output array)

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have wrapped native code from http://answers.opencv.org/question/22941/sauvola-thresholding-for-android/ to use in my android project as follows:

doThreshold function in Thresholder.cpp

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_packagename_MainActivity_doThreshold
(JNIEnv* env, jobject  thiz, InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, const     BhThresholdMethod &method)

{
Mat src = _src.getMat();
int winx = 0;
int winy = 0;
float optK=0.5;
if (winx==0 || winy==0) {
    winy = (int) (2.0 * src.rows - 1)/3;
    winx = (int) src.cols-1 < winy ? src.cols-1 : winy;

    // if the window is too big, than we asume that the image
    // is not a single text box, but a document page: set
    // the window size to a fixed constant.
    if (winx > 100)
        winx = winy = 40;
}
// Threshold
_dst.create(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
Mat dst = _dst.getMat();

//medianBlur(src,dst,5);
GaussianBlur(src,dst,Size(5,5),0);

//#define _BH_SHOW_IMAGE
#ifdef _BH_DEBUG
#define _BH_SHOW_IMAGE
#endif
//medianBlur(src,dst,7);
switch (method)
{
case BhThresholdMethod::OTSU :
    threshold(dst,dst,128,255,CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    break;
case BhThresholdMethod::SAUVOLA :
case BhThresholdMethod::WOLFJOLION :
    NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion (src, dst, method, winx, winy, optK, 128);
}
bitwise_not(dst,dst);


#ifdef _BH_SHOW_IMAGE

#undef _BH_SHOW_IMAGE
#endif
}
```

My MainActivity.java contains:

```
private native void doThreshold(Mat src, Mat dst, BhThresholdMethod method);
static {
  System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
  System.loadLibrary("thresholder");
}
```

And then I call the native method by doing:

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("test.jpg");
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bin);
Mat image = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, image);
//call native method
doThreshold(image, image, BhThresholdMethod.SAUVOLA);
```

But then I get this error:

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Null pointer (create() called for the missing output array)
in void cv::_OutputArray::create(int, const int*, int, int, bool, int) const, file 
/Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2437
```

The error gets thrown inside Thresholder.cpp when it gets to this line of code: `_dst.create(src.size(), CV_8UC1);`

If I understand it correctly, it seems that it's trying to use `OutputArray::Create(int, const int*, int, int, bool, int)` instead of `Mat::Create(Size size, int type)`

Can someone explain to me why it is doing this or what I did wrong?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem,i.e., I'm trying to populate an OutputArray but I'm having trouble doing it.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, in the end I used an API that did all the work for me.